# Cancel main trigger after running (after update) trigger type

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I made a trigger that is an "update after type" and this update command (inside it) can invoke a main trigger again. How to say to SQL Server if after update trigger is invoked then main trigger not invoked again.

Comment: Share your code please

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, why are you updating the table again inside the trigger? Sounds like you may want to use and `Instead of Trigger`.

Comment: i have a dore_number field in our table i need to update again a table by some conditions this is related to dore_number.so main trigger get history of previous data and second trigger do action according to conditions

Answer (score 2):

1. **Using `COLUMNS_UPDATED()`**

To prevent a trigger recursing indefinitely when updating the table from within the trigger you can test which columns have been updated using [`COLUMNS_UPDATED()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/columns-updated-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and then return when the update pattern can only be from within your trigger. e.g.

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[MyTable_Trigger]
on [dbo].[MyTable]
for insert, update, delete
as
begin
  set nocount on;

  declare @ColumnsUpdated varbinary(10) = COLUMNS_UPDATED();

  -- Ignore trigger updates
  -- Identify specific pattern for trigger update, knowing it may change if the table structure changes
  if @ColumnsUpdated = 0x00000000000000008000 return;

  -- rest of trigger
end
```

2. **Using `@@NESTLEVEL`**

You can use [`@@NESTLEVEL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/nestlevel-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to detect whether you are within the first trigger call or a later trigger call. For a straight update the `@@NESTLEVEL` will be 1 in the trigger the first call and 2 the second. This will increase if you perform the update from within a stored procedure - once for each nested stored procedure.

Comment: A note for `@@NESTLEVEL`, it also increases with nested SPs. So if an SP calls another SP that calls another SP which fires the trigger, the nested level is gonna be 4 (or 3?).

Comment: @EzLo yes that why I said it will increase if called from within an SP - but I assume OP will read the docs :)

Answer (score 1):

> **Recursive Triggers**
>
> An AFTER trigger does not call itself recursively unless the
>   RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS database option is set.

From docs: [Recursive Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/create-nested-triggers?view=sql-server-2017#recursive-triggers)